# How to check whether STL iterator points at anything?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ Best way to check if an iterator is valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062956/c-best-way-to-check-if-an-iterator-is-valid)

I want to do something like this:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator it;
// /cut/ search for something in vector and point iterator at it. 
if(!it) //check whether found
    do_something();
```

But there is no operator! for iterators. How can I check whether iterator points at anything?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use an iterator without any reference to the container it's iterating. See James Hopkin's answer.

Comment: clarifying the darkness Invalidation of STL Iterators: http://www.angelikalanger.com/Conferences/Slides/CppInvalidIterators-DevConnections-2002.pdf

Comment: Vote to reopen because: 1) target question is newer, so it should be the other a duplicate of this one. 2) The question is not the seame: this ask if the iterator is not the ending iterator, while the other ask for invalidated iterators.

Answer (score 49):

You can't. The usual idiom is to use the container's end iterator as a 'not found' marker. This is what `std::find` returns.

```
std::vector<int>::iterator i = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), 13);
if (i != v.end())
{
     // ...
}
```

The only thing you can do with an unassigned iterator is assign a value to it.

Comment: You covered the case when the iterator is initialized and still valid. However, some operations on some containers may invalidate the iterators. For example, removal of elements from a vector may invalidate iterators ( the iterator pointing to the last element in the vector in this case).

Comment: @Cătălin: that's all true, but out of the scope of the question, I think. Just as the ! (`not`) operator will only work with valid or null pointers, the above will only work with valid iterators (including `end` iterators).

Comment: Iterator validity is in the programmer's scope of things to worry about. YOU are the only that need to make sure you are not doing something nasty with your iterators.

Answer (score 2):

Though the iterators are considered as general form of pointers, they are not exactly the  pointers. The standard defines `Past-the-end` iterator  to indicate the search failure in containers. Hence, it is not recommended to check the iterators for NULL

`Past-the-end` values are nonsingular and nondereferenceable.

```
if(it != aVector.end())  //past-the-end iterator
    do_something();
```

Comment: Nonsingular????

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use iterator in a loop, the safest way to use it is in this fashion:

```
for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
{
 do_smth();
}
```

Comment: Actually many standard algorithms return iterators (e.g. find) and methods on containers (e.g. map::find)

Comment: It's safe unless the loop does 'erase(it)' because after the erase, 'it' becomes invalid and subsequent '++it' is invalid.

Comment: Does not answer the question

Answer (score -2):

I believe this should generally give you a good test:

```
if (iterator._Mycont == &MyContainer)
{
Probably a valid iterator!
}
```

You could do tests to make sure that the iterator does not equal the end...

```
iterator != MyContainer.end()
```

and:

```
iterator >= MyContainer.begin()
```

Comment: Seems extremely compiler (and version!) dependent.