# How to check if simple C++ standard library iterator can be advanced?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

Suppose I have a class encapsulating std container:

```
class Stash
{
    list<int> Data;

public:
    list<int>::const_iterator GetAccess() const { return Data.begin(); }
};
```

It's very convenient way of forcing the user to read the data in form of the iterator. However, I can't find the way other that comparing the iterator to `container.end()`. So, I would like to know if there's an option to do it solely by stdlib or I have to write iterator class myself (with `can_advance` method, for example).

Relevant question might be [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062956/c-best-way-to-check-if-an-iterator-is-valid), but it asks whether the iterator *is valid*, not whether it *can advance*. I weren't able to find any information about the latter.

Comment: You can't :( And you need 15 chars to post a comment.

Comment: This is one of the reasons a `yield` keyword would be helpful. :/

Comment: If you explain why in answer, I will accept it. I can't accept a comment ;)

Comment: Check out `boost::range` http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov Unfortunately, I can't use boost in the thing I am currently working on; other than that, it's certainly better.

Comment: @Bartek, you can certainly use the idea in your own code.

Comment: @Nikolai, well, the `pair<iterator,iterator>` is simple enough for now. I don't think I need anything more complicated. Thanks for the input, though.

Comment: `boost::range` is effectively just that, except that it offers `begin()` and `end()` methods (and the needed typedefs you can get from `std::iterator`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this, a single iterator does not contain the information when it is at the end of the sequence its pointing into.

Normally, this is solved by either providing a range (think `std::make_pair(cont.begin(), cont.end())`), or providing `begin()` and `end()` methods to your class, effectively making it a range.

Comment: Can I safely compare to the stored `.end()` later on? I mean, is it always valid, even if the container's items change?

Comment: @Bartek: Depends on the container's iterator invalidation semantics. With `std::list`, it's fine. However, you shouldn't modify the container while iterating over it, that is normally considered *bad*.

Answer (score 2):

Iterators work in pairs: an iterator that points to the beginning of a sequence and an iterator that points past the end of the sequence. That's why all the containers have `begin()` and `end()` member functions: so you can look at the sequence of values that the container manages.

It would be far more idiomatic to change the name of `GetAccess` to `begin` and to add `end`. Having `end()` would also make it possible to apply standard algorithms to the data.

Comment: +1 for possibility of applying standard algorithms to the returned iterator.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be asking for is a "lookahead" iterator. You could write a class to "adapt" an iterator to have lookahead, where the adaptor just stays one step ahead of your code:

```
template<class FwdIter>
class lookahead_iterator
{
public:
    lookahead_iterator(const FwdIter& begin): cur_iter(begin), next_iter(++begin) {}
    operator FwdIter() const { return cur_iter; }
    lookahead_iterator<FwdIter>& operator ++() { cur_iter = next_iter++; return *this; }
    // Other methods as needed.
private:
    FwdIter cur_iter;
    FwdIter next_iter;
};
```

Needless to say, this gets a lot more complicated if you need more than a forward iterator.

Comment: I suppose `operator FwdIter() const { return cur_iter; }` was to be either `operator FwdIter ...` or `FwdIter operator() ...`

Comment: It's supposed to be an overload for the typecast operator, invoked by explicit or implicit `static_cast<FwdIter>(my_lookahead_operator)` or `(FwdIter)my_lookahead_operator`. It's definitely not `operator()`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. See http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/910-overloading-typecasts/ for an intro on overloading typecast operators.