# Is this a singular iterator and, if so, can I compare it to another one?

Tags: c++, iterator, std, c++03

I always thought that a "singular" iterator was one that has been default-initialised, and these could serve as comparable *sentinel* values of sorts:

```
typedef std::vector<Elem>::iterator I;
I start = I();

std::vector<Elem> container = foo();

for (I it = container.begin(), end = container.end(); it != end; ++it) {
   if ((start == I()) && bar(it)) {
      // Does something only the first time bar(it) is satisfied

      // ...

      start = it;
   }
}
```

But [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2062986/560648) suggests not only that my definition of "singular" is wrong, but also that my comparison above is totally illegal.

Is it?

Comment: I don’t think the answer implies that your code is illegal, only that your nomenclature was wrong. It might still be illegal, mind. At the very least you failed to default-initialise `start` – for PODs, its value *is* singular (and your code illegal).

Comment: @Konrad: Oops, yes, default-initialisation intended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obviously this will work for *some* iterators - `T*` being a clear example - but it's definitely not guaranteed correct behavior for *all* iterators.  C++11 24.2.1 [iterator.requirements.general] p5:

> *Singular values* are not associated with any sequence ... Results of most expressions are undefined for singular values; the only
>   exceptions are destroying an iterator that holds a singular value, the
>   assignment of a non-singular value to an iterator that holds a
>   singular value, and, for iterators that satisfy the
>   DefaultConstructible requirements, using a value-initialized iterator
>   as the source of a copy or move operation.

You can replicate your desired behavior with a simple `bool` flag:

```
std::vector<Elem> container = foo();
bool did_it_already = false;

for (I it = container.begin(), end = container.end(); it != end; ++it) {
   if (!did_it_already && bar(it)) {
      // Does something only the first time bar(it) is satisfied

      // ...

      did_it_already = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to find an explicit citation that says "default constructed iterators may be singular", but it doesn't seem to exist; I think it's only implicit.

Comment: @PeteBecker The possibly-singular iterator in question (`start`) is compared with another default-constructed iterator, not with the end iterator of any sequence, I don't see how your comments apply.

Comment: Was hoping this would be a handy way to avoid that `bool`. Bah!

Comment: The standard quote seems to clearly answer my question. Thanks.