# Checking if iterator is not assigned to item when there is no specific container

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I want to search for a value in two `std::vector`'s. If it was found in one of them I want to return its iterator. If not, I want to return some value which indicates that it was not found.

In normal situation where only one `std::vector` is involved, I would return `std::vector::end`. What should I do in this situation?

**Normal situation:**

```
auto find_ten=[](const std::vector<int>& v){
    return std::find(v.cbegin(),v.cend(),10);
}
```

**My situation:**

```
auto find_ten=[](const std::vector<int>& v1,const std::vector<int>& v2){
    auto it1=std::find(v1.cbegin(),v1.cend(),10);
    if(it1==v1.cend()){
        auto it2=std::find(v2.cbegin(),v2.cend(),10);
        if(it2==v2.cend()){
             //What should I return here??
        }
        return it2;
    }
    return it1;
}
```

I want to return something that I can check it later to know that the number `10` was not found in any of them.

Comment: An iterator is _never_ "null".

Comment: (Though a singular iterator may help you, you're allowed to do surprisingly little with one.)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit corrected

Comment: I would return the index in the array instead, or -1 if not found. This could be done by diffing the `begin()` and iterator pointers. But maybe that's lame.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre returning index means that you have to return a clue to which vector its belong

Comment: If the caller is to remain blissfully unaware of the two vectors, then a sentinel is probably your best choice. Create a dummy vector that is part of your public interface and return its end().

Comment: To back up my earlier comment, be warned! [The "obvious" solution is not all it's cracked up to be.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17198239/560648)

Comment: You should be using `boost::join` to join ranges anyway. Then this is trivial.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks you made it clear

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since C++14 you are allowed to compare value-initialized iterators if they meet the ForwardIterator category or stronger (see [forward.iterators] paragraph 2). A value-initialized iterator is the equivalent of a null pointer, so you can use:

```
    if(it2==v2.cend()){
         return std::vector<int>::iterator{};
    }
```

And then the caller can do:

```
std::vector<int>::iterator not_found{};
auto find_ten = ...
if (find_ten != not_found)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. it seems exactly what I am looking for. But I can not use C++ 14 yet.

Comment: In practice it will probably work with any version of C++ (except in iterator debugging modes), the C++14 standard just made it officially legal

Comment: Ah That is great then

Comment: Until c++14, just declare a private vector<int> foo and have not_found() return end(foo). This becomes your sentinel value

Comment: But are you allowed to actually compare a value-initialized iterator with a "normal" iterator (in the "found" case)? [N3644](http://wg21.link/N3644) actually says this is UB in the discussion ("The result of comparing a value-initialized iterator to an iterator with a non-singular value is undefined.").

Comment: @T.C. Good point. That seems to severely limit the usefulness of the feature, so it's only useful in cases very similar to the ::begin() / A::end() example in N3644. Even if it remains undefined for the general case, it would be helpful if the standard containers supported such comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

```
auto find_ten=[](const std::vector<int>& v1,const std::vector<int>& v2){
    auto it1=std::find(v1.cbegin(),v1.cend(),10);
    if(it1==v1.cend()){
        auto it2=std::find(v2.cbegin(),v2.cend(),10);        
        return it2; // whether it's end or not
    }
    return it1;
}
```

when using, just test `(rval != v2.end())`  (rval is the returned iterator). I know, that's not very symmetric.

OR

Pass a boolean as `out` parameter

```
auto find_ten=[](const std::vector<int>& v1,const std::vector<int>& v2, bool &found){
    found = true; // suppose we will find it

    auto it1=std::find(v1.cbegin(),v1.cend(),10);
    if(it1==v1.cend()){
        auto it2=std::find(v2.cbegin(),v2.cend(),10);  
        found = it2 != v2.end();     // false if not in v1 or in v2
        return it2; // whether it's end or not
    }

    return it1;
}
```

Comment: Really? Is it well-defined to compare iterators from different containers? In my experience, `for (auto it = contA.begin(), end = contB.end(); it != end; ++it)` does not go well.

Comment: I agree this is not very academic, hence my alternate solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply return the right-most vector's end iterator, this makes logical sense:

```
auto find_ten=[](const std::vector<int>& v1,const std::vector<int>& v2){
    auto it1=std::find(v1.cbegin(),v1.cend(),10);
    if(it1==v1.cend()){
        return std::find(v2.cbegin(),v2.cend(),10);
    }
    return it1;
}

auto it = find_ten(v1, v2);
if (it == v2.end()) // no luck
```

Or you could take an iterator argument:

```
auto find_ten=[](const std::vector<int>& v1,const std::vector<int>& v2, std::vector<int>::iterator endit){
    auto it1=std::find(v1.cbegin(),v1.cend(),10);
    if(it1==v1.cend()){
        auto it2=std::find(v2.cbegin(),v2.cend(),10);
        if(it2==v2.cend()){
             return endit;
        }
        return it2;
    }
    return it1;
}
```

These both, of course, depend on your use case: if you're going to use the returned iterator for more than just direct access to an element, you'll need to consider a different approach:

--- EDIT ---

If you need to use the iterator beyond just direct access to the offending element, you could use `std::reference_wrapper` to let you return a reference to the offending vector (or you could just return a pointer).

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using find_ten_t = std::pair<std::reference_wrapper<const std::vector<int>>, std::vector<int>::const_iterator>;

auto find_ten = [](const std::vector<int>& v1, const std::vector<int>& v2) -> find_ten_t {
    auto it1 = std::find(v1.cbegin(), v1.cend(), 10);
    if (it1 != v1.cend()) {
        return std::make_pair(std::ref(v1), it1);
    }
    auto it2 = std::find(v2.cbegin(), v2.cend(), 10);
    return std::make_pair(std::cref(v2), it2);
};

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v1{ 1, 2, 3 };
    std::vector<int> v2{ 3, 4, 10 };
    auto r = find_ten(v1, v2);
    std::cout << "r.first[0] = " << r.first.get()[0] << "\n";
}
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/cNLJKg

Comment: @HumamHelfawi If you need more than direct access, see edit.

Answer (score 1):

Not really brilliant, I suppose, but... I propose returning a `std::pair` where the first element is an int (0 for "not found", 1 for "found in first" and 2 for "found in second") and the second is the iterator.

Something like

```
auto find_ten=[](const std::vector<int>& v1,const std::vector<int>& v2){
    auto it1=std::find(v1.cbegin(),v1.cend(),10);
    if(it1==v1.cend()){
        auto it2=std::find(v2.cbegin(),v2.cend(),10);
        if(it2==v2.cend()){
            return std::make_pair(0, v1.cend()); // or make_pair(0, v2.cend())
        }
        return std::make_pair(2, it2);
    }
    return std::make_pair(1, it1);
};
```

Or better: you could return a pair of iterator where the second is the `cend()` of the corresponding vector; something like

```
auto find_ten=[](const std::vector<int>& v1,const std::vector<int>& v2){
    auto it1=std::find(v1.cbegin(),v1.cend(),10);
    if(it1==v1.cend()){
       return std::make_pair(std::find(v2.cbegin(),v2.cend(),10), v2.cend());
    }
    return std::make_pair(it1, v1.cend());
};
```

I think it's important to return the `cend()` correspindig iterator because I suppose you want to use the iterator pointing to 10 and you could iterate it.

Obvioulsy, If you're **only** interested in knowing if 10 is present in `v1` or in `v2`, I suppose you should returning a `bool`: `true` for "found", `false` otherwise; something like

```
auto find_ten=[](const std::vector<int>& v1,const std::vector<int>& v2){
    auto ret = v1.cend() != std::find(v1.cbegin(),v1.cend(),10);
    if ( ret == false )
       ret = v2.cend() != std::find(v2.cbegin(),v2.cend(),10);
    return ret;
};
```

p.s.: sorry for my bad English.

Comment: @Jarod42 - I imagine that the use `std::option` can be a solution but... can be my limit...  I don't understand the usefulness of returning a const-iterator without informations regarding the container that is referenced.

Comment: @Jarod42 - nobody is perfect :-)