# Is Undefined Behavior To Using Invalid Iterator?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

Consider this code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int  main()
{
  std::map<std::string, std::string>  map = {
    { "ghasem", "another" }
  };
  std::cout << map.find("another")->second << std::endl;
  std::cout << map.size() << std::endl;
}
```

It will be compiled and run successfully(the process return value is `0`), but we couldn't see the output of `map.size()`. Neither `-fsanitize=address` nor `-fsanitize=undfined` reports any problem. I compiled with GCC-11.2.1 and Clang-13.0.0, both are the same. And running the code step by step using GDB-11.1-5 will not help and all the steps will be run successfully.

But if I reorder the last two lines:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int  main()
{
  std::map<std::string, std::string>  map = {
    { "ghasem", "another" }
  };
  std::cout << map.size() << std::endl;
  std::cout << map.find("another")->second << std::endl;
}
```

I will get a Segmentation Fault and now ASAN could report the error.

---

And my question here is: Is the code cause some sort of Undefined Behavior? How could I detect those errors?

---

**Environment:**

- **OS**: <kbd>Fedora 35</kbd>
- **Compiler(s)**:

  - <kbd>GCC 11.2.1</kbd>
  - <kbd>Clang 13.0.0</kbd>
- **Additional Compiler Flags:**
- **Debugger:** <kbd>GDB 11.1-5</kbd>

Comment: `<bits/stdc++.h>` is not something you should be including yourself. If you want `std::map`, that properly comes from `<map>`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking if an iterator is valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062956/checking-if-an-iterator-is-valid)

Comment: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) Any resource teaching you to use it should be shunned like the plague. If you truly want to learn programming and C++, please invest in [some good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and perhaps even take classes.

Comment: Compile first code with -O2 and `-fsanitize=address` throws something.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, That is just for simplifying the code snippet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no key comparing equal to `"another"` in the map. Therefore `map.find("another")` will return the `.end()` iterator of the map. Dereferencing this iterator in `->second` is then undefined behavior since end iterators may not be dereferenced.

Your code should check that the iterator returned from `find` is not the end iterator, i.e. that an element has been found.

In terms of debugging, if you are using libstdc++ as standard library implementation (which is the case with GCC and potentially with Clang), you can use `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG`on the compiler invocation to enable debug assertions in the standard library implementation which will detect this issue.